# Migrate Magento to Subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

I am migrating my Magento site to a subdomain "test.magentostore.com". I copied all files, imported the DB, changed the URL in the `core_config` table from `https://www.magentostore.com` to `http://test.magentostore.com` and have disabled SSL via SQL.

However, when I try to open the admin site, it forces me to `https` and gives me an error. Same happens with home page. When I don't have an `.htaccess` file on the server, then the home page opens, but other urls don't work as Rewrite is not active.

Any ideas what I can do to fix this?

Comment: delete everything inside var folder

Answer (score 0):

DB has two url items for every store in core_config_data tabel: `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`.

Make sure to change both from https to http.

There is also items `web/secure/use_in_frontend` and `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml`. You can change these values from 1 to 0 to make sure.

Comment: I did all of it before posting the question - didn't help. Think it has something to do with the `.htaccess` file but not sure what...any other ideas?

Comment: I used this [link](https://github.com/nexcess/magento/blob/master/.htaccess.sample)